# PHP set cookie array json cyrillic

Tags: php, arrays, setcookie, cyrillic

Oh guys, i spending second day on this stuff trying and catching errors one by one on localhost and hosting and still can't recognize what problem is :(

For example i have an array like that:

```
$wishlistArray = array
    (
    array(
    'id' => '1021397549', 
    'prod-name' => 'Продукт 1',
    'cost' => '4', 
    'sku' => '14:200001438#8;5:361385', 
    'pcs' => '1',
    'ship-num' => '2',
    'ship-name' => 'DHL', 
    'ship-cost' => '2400',
    'img' => 'http://i01.i.site.com/wsphoto/v15/1021397549_1/2014-новая-прекрасная-Продукт1.jpg',
    'aviable' => '999',
    'sku-html' => '<img class="color" height="26" width="26" src="http://i01.i.site.com/wsphoto/sku/v12/1021397549/1021397549_200001438/Хаки-2015-новый-шик-горячая-распродажа-бесплатная-доставка-сексуальные-женщины-красочные-птицы-шифон-рубашка-форме-крыла-летучей.jpg_50x50.jpg" title="8" bigpic="http://i01.i.site.com/wsphoto/sku/v12/1021397549/1021397549_200001438/Хаки-2015-новый-шик-горячая-распродажа-бесплатная-доставка-сексуальные-женщины-красочные-птицы-шифон-рубашка-форме-крыла-летучей.jpg">'
    ),
    array(
    'id' => '2028047220',
    'prod-name' => 'Продукт 2',
    'cost' => '9'   , 
    'sku' => '', 
    'pcs' => '2', 
    'ship-num' => '2',
    'ship-name' => 'EMS',
    'ship-cost' => '1428',
    'img' => 'http://i00.i.site.com/wsphoto/v1/1735472674_1/Продукт2-супер-изображение.jpg',
    'aviable' => '999',
    'sku-html' => ''
    )
    );
```

I am trying to save it as cookie, because i would echo it with Javascript little bit next:

```
$someJSON = json_encode($wishlistArray);
setcookie("wishlist", $someJSON);
$decode_array = json_decode($_COOKIE["wishlist"]); 
echo 'FROM COOKIE: <pre>', print_r($decode_array), '</pre>';
```

But here it stops with different errors from **500** to **Notice:  Undefined variable:** and **Notice: Undefined index:** when i am trying tweak it with some *raw_json_encode*, *addslashes*, *ob_start();* and etc, so I think main problem actually in converting Array right way before Settings Up Cookie.

I pray all gods guys, my head going crazy, really don't understand how to do this :(

**UPDATE:**

This is clear string after json conversion that i am trying to set as cookie and get no cookie after :(

```
[{"id":"1021397549","prod-name":"2015 \u043d\u043e\u0432\u044b\u0439 \u0448\u0438\u043a! \u0433\u043e\u0440\u044f\u0447\u0430\u044f \u0440\u0430\u0441\u043f\u0440\u043e\u0434\u0430\u0436\u0430 \u0431\u0435\u0441\u043f\u043b\u0430\u0442\u043d\u0430\u044f \u0434\u043e\u0441\u0442\u0430\u0432\u043a\u0430 \u0441\u0435\u043a\u0441\u0443\u0430\u043b\u044c\u043d\u044b\u0435 \u0436\u0435\u043d\u0449\u0438\u043d\u044b \u043a\u0440\u0430\u0441\u043e\u0447\u043d\u044b\u0435 \u043f\u0442\u0438\u0446\u044b \u0448\u0438\u0444\u043e\u043d \u0440\u0443\u0431\u0430\u0448\u043a\u0430 \u0444\u043e\u0440\u043c\u0435 \u043a\u0440\u044b\u043b\u0430 \u043b\u0435\u0442\u0443\u0447\u0435\u0439 \u043c\u044b\u0448\u0438 \u0448\u0438\u0440\u043e\u043a\u0438\u0439 \u0431\u043b\u0443\u0437\u043a\u0438 \u0441\u0432\u043e\u0431\u043e\u0434\u043d\u043e\u0433\u043e \u043f\u043e\u043a\u0440\u043e\u044f \u0442\u043e\u043f\u044b","cost":147,"sku":"14:200001438#8;5:361385","pcs":"1","ship-num":"2","ship-name":"e-EMS","ship-cost":796,"img":"http:\/\/i01.i.aliimg.com\/wsphoto\/v15\/1021397549_1\/2015-\u043d\u043e\u0432\u044b\u0439-\u0448\u0438\u043a-\u0433\u043e\u0440\u044f\u0447\u0430\u044f-\u0440\u0430\u0441\u043f\u0440\u043e\u0434\u0430\u0436\u0430-\u0431\u0435\u0441\u043f\u043b\u0430\u0442\u043d\u0430\u044f-\u0434\u043e\u0441\u0442\u0430\u0432\u043a\u0430-\u0441\u0435\u043a\u0441\u0443\u0430\u043b\u044c\u043d\u044b\u0435-\u0436\u0435\u043d\u0449\u0438\u043d\u044b-\u043a\u0440\u0430\u0441\u043e\u0447\u043d\u044b\u0435-\u043f\u0442\u0438\u0446\u044b-\u0448\u0438\u0444\u043e\u043d-\u0440\u0443\u0431\u0430\u0448\u043a\u0430-\u0444\u043e\u0440\u043c\u0435-\u043a\u0440\u044b\u043b\u0430-\u043b\u0435\u0442\u0443\u0447\u0435\u0439.jpg","aviable":"990","sku-html":""},{"id":"2028047220","prod-name":"2015 \u043d\u043e\u0432\u044b\u0439 \u0448\u0438\u043a! \u0433\u043e\u0440\u044f\u0447\u0430\u044f \u0440\u0430\u0441\u043f\u0440\u043e\u0434\u0430\u0436\u0430 \u0431\u0435\u0441\u043f\u043b\u0430\u0442\u043d\u0430\u044f \u0434\u043e\u0441\u0442\u0430\u0432\u043a\u0430 \u0441\u0435\u043a\u0441\u0443\u0430\u043b\u044c\u043d\u044b\u0435 \u0436\u0435\u043d\u0449\u0438\u043d\u044b \u043a\u0440\u0430\u0441\u043e\u0447\u043d\u044b\u0435 \u043f\u0442\u0438\u0446\u044b \u0448\u0438\u0444\u043e\u043d \u0440\u0443\u0431\u0430\u0448\u043a\u0430 \u0444\u043e\u0440\u043c\u0435 \u043a\u0440\u044b\u043b\u0430 \u043b\u0435\u0442\u0443\u0447\u0435\u0439 \u043c\u044b\u0448\u0438 \u0448\u0438\u0440\u043e\u043a\u0438\u0439 \u0431\u043b\u0443\u0437\u043a\u0438 \u0441\u0432\u043e\u0431\u043e\u0434\u043d\u043e\u0433\u043e \u043f\u043e\u043a\u0440\u043e\u044f \u0442\u043e\u043f\u044b 14003","cost":136,"sku":"","pcs":"2","ship-num":"2","ship-name":"China Post Registered Air Mail","ship-cost":110,"img":"http:\/\/i00.i.aliimg.com\/wsphoto\/v0\/2028047220_1\/2015-\u043d\u043e\u0432\u044b\u0439-\u0448\u0438\u043a-\u0433\u043e\u0440\u044f\u0447\u0430\u044f-\u0440\u0430\u0441\u043f\u0440\u043e\u0434\u0430\u0436\u0430-\u0431\u0435\u0441\u043f\u043b\u0430\u0442\u043d\u0430\u044f-\u0434\u043e\u0441\u0442\u0430\u0432\u043a\u0430-\u0441\u0435\u043a\u0441\u0443\u0430\u043b\u044c\u043d\u044b\u0435-\u0436\u0435\u043d\u0449\u0438\u043d\u044b-\u043a\u0440\u0430\u0441\u043e\u0447\u043d\u044b\u0435-\u043f\u0442\u0438\u0446\u044b-\u0448\u0438\u0444\u043e\u043d-\u0440\u0443\u0431\u0430\u0448\u043a\u0430-\u0444\u043e\u0440\u043c\u0435-\u043a\u0440\u044b\u043b\u0430-\u043b\u0435\u0442\u0443\u0447\u0435\u0439.jpg","aviable":"998","sku-html":""},{"id":"802048809","prod-name":"\u0414\u0438\u0437\u0430\u0439\u043d\u0435\u0440 \u0438\u0441\u043a\u0443\u0441\u0441\u0442\u0432\u0435\u043d\u043d\u043e\u0433\u043e \u0438\u0437 \u0434\u0432\u0443\u0445 \u0447\u0430\u0441\u0442\u0435\u0439 \u043a\u0440\u0443\u0436\u0435\u0432\u0430 \u0448\u0438\u0444\u043e\u043d \u0431\u043b\u0443\u0437\u043a\u0430 \u0440\u0443\u0431\u0430\u0448\u043a\u0430 \u0441 \u043a\u0430\u0440\u0434\u0438\u0433\u0430\u043d \u0434\u043b\u044f \u0436\u0435\u043d\u0449\u0438\u043d 2015 \u0432\u0435\u0441\u043d\u0430 \u043c\u043e\u0434\u0430 \u0434\u0430\u043c\u044b \u0441\u0432\u043e\u0431\u043e\u0434\u043d\u043e\u0433\u043e \u043f\u043e\u043a\u0440\u043e\u044f \u0442\u043e\u043f\u044b","cost":585,"sku":"","pcs":"1","ship-num":"3","ship-name":"Fedex IE","ship-cost":3865,"img":"http:\/\/i01.i.aliimg.com\/wsphoto\/v0\/802048809\/\u0414\u0438\u0437\u0430\u0439\u043d\u0435\u0440-\u0438\u0441\u043a\u0443\u0441\u0441\u0442\u0432\u0435\u043d\u043d\u043e\u0433\u043e-\u0438\u0437-\u0434\u0432\u0443\u0445-\u0447\u0430\u0441\u0442\u0435\u0439-\u043a\u0440\u0443\u0436\u0435\u0432\u0430-\u0448\u0438\u0444\u043e\u043d-\u0431\u043b\u0443\u0437\u043a\u0430-\u0440\u0443\u0431\u0430\u0448\u043a\u0430-\u0441-\u043a\u0430\u0440\u0434\u0438\u0433\u0430\u043d-\u0434\u043b\u044f-\u0436\u0435\u043d\u0449\u0438\u043d-2015-\u0432\u0435\u0441\u043d\u0430-\u043c\u043e\u0434\u0430.jpg","aviable":"919","sku-html":""}]
```

Comment: What is output of $decode_array ?

Comment: actually `<pre>1</pre>` and there is no cookie **wishlist** at all actually too, but when i sets it's with something simple like `setcookie("wishlist", "cookie_test");` it appears :)

Comment: Which line, containing your code doead Notice: Undefined variable emplies

Comment: note that the one you set on cookies will be available on the next request. and you should have `true` flag parameter on `print_r`

Comment: At which lines exactly do the errors occur, and what are the complete error messages?

Comment: using these code there is no error appears at all, but cookie didn't sets(
`$someJSON = raw_json_encode($wishlistArray);
setcookie("wishlist", $someJSON);
$decode_array = json_decode($_COOKIE["wishlist"]); 
echo 'UPDATED ARRAY: <pre>', print_r($wishlistArray), '</pre>';
 
 echo 'FROM COOKIE: <pre>', print_r($decode_array), '</pre>';`

Answer (score 0):

First of all `json_decode` requires `TRUE`-alike second parameter to return associative array as result.
Then check that you are using correct encoding, because `json_decode` will return UTF-8 encoded strings here.

Answer (score 0):

**PHP part Solved** with base64_encode

```
   ob_start();

    header("Content-Type:text/html;charset=utf-8"); 

    function raw_json_encode($input) {

            return preg_replace_callback(
            '/\\\\u([0-9a-zA-Z]{4})/',
            function ($matches) {
                return mb_convert_encoding(pack('H*',$matches[1]),'UTF-8','UTF-16');
            },
            json_encode($input)
            );

        }

    $someJSON = base64_encode(raw_json_encode($wishlistArray));
    setcookie("wishlist", $someJSON);
    $decode_array = json_decode(base64_decode($_COOKIE["wishlist"])); 

    echo 'FROM COOKIE: <pre>', print_r($decode_array), '</pre>';
```

**Javascript part not Solved** So I just need to realized how to decode it back in Javascritpt, because

```
        <script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/components/core-min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/components/enc-utf16-min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/components/enc-base64-min.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="src/jquery.cookie.js"></script>

<div id="myCart"></div>

    <script>
        var wishlistArray = JSON.parse(CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse($.cookie('wishlist')));


            var wishlistArrayDom = "";
            jQuery.each(wishlistArray, function (i, wishlistID) { 
                wishlistArrayDom += '<br><div><b>' 
                +               
                wishlistID["id"] + ' ' +
                wishlistID["prod-name"] + ' ' +
                wishlistID["cost"] + ' ' +
                wishlistID["sku"] + ' ' +
                wishlistID["pcs"] + ' ' +
                wishlistID["ship-num"] + ' ' +
                wishlistID["ship-name"] + ' ' +
                wishlistID["ship-cost"] + ' ' +
                wishlistID["img"] + ' ' +
                wishlistID["aviable"] 
                +
                '<br>';

            });

            $('#myCart').empty();
            $('#myCart').html(wishlistArrayDom); 

        }
    </script>
```

doesn't work at all and i somehow getting **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token b** on **1 breakpoint**.